# MYSQL WHERE Clause doesnt work, after joining tables?

Tags: mysql

i am trying to display some data about a specific id and THATS where the WHERE Clause comes in place, but it doens't work.
By the way in wp_posts the user_id is the wp_users.ID.

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, post_name FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_users.ID = user_id
ORDER BY wp_users.ID
WHERE wp_users.ID="2"
```

This works and displays the wp_users.ID and post_name but if i want to display only the post_names of a specific ID with this line 'WHERE wp_users.ID="2"' it doesn't work.

New to MySQL

Comment: The `where` clause should go before the `order by`

Comment: in the future, do avoid saying things like "doesn't work"; show what *does* happen (in this case, show the error message).

Comment: from/join/where/group by/having/order by/limit all have to appear in that specific order; you can't rearrange them

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind it works now

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, post_name 
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = user_id
WHERE wp_users.ID="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to fix the query for you, in some way that makes sense to me:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.post_name 
FROM wp_users A
  LEFT JOIN wp_posts B ON A.ID = B.user_id
WHERE A.ID='2'
ORDER BY B.ID
```

Assuming:
table wp_users(ID,...) ID is Primary key
table wp_posts(ID, user_id,...) ID is Primary key and user_id is foreign key references wp_users(ID)
A and B are alias... I alwais use them (and DBMS also loves them).

Hope it helps